# Flutter FFMPEG: The BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance value is invalid until BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized is executed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ffmpeg

Hey guys I have a function that uses `ffmpeg` to convert images to `gifs`. I am using the simple compute function provided by flutter, but I am getting this error.

> I/flutter (12889): Loading ffmpeg-kit-flutter. E/flutter (12889):
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: Bad state: The BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance
> value is invalid until
> BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized is executed.
> E/flutter (12889): #0 BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance

**Logs:**

> I/flutter (12889): Loading ffmpeg-kit-flutter. E/flutter (12889):
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: Bad state: The BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance
> value is invalid until
> BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized is executed.
> E/flutter (12889): #0      BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance
> (package:flutter/src/services/_background_isolate_binary_messenger_io.dart:27:7)
> E/flutter (12889): #1      _findBinaryMessenger
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:135:42) E/flutter
> (12889): #2      EventChannel.binaryMessenger
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:619:27) E/flutter
> (12889): #3      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream. (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:639:7)
> E/flutter (12889): #4      _runGuarded
> (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:815:24) E/flutter (12889): #5
> _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:207:7) E/flutter (12889):
> #6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:828:19) E/flutter (12889): #7
> _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:471:9) E/flutter (12889): #8      FFmpegKitInitializer._initialize
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_initializer.dart:311:44)
> E/flutter (12889): #9      FFmpegKitInitializer.initialize
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_initializer.dart:54:23)
> E/flutter (12889): #10     FFmpegKitConfig.init
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_kit_config.dart:50:32)
> E/flutter (12889): #11     AbstractSession.createFFmpegSession
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/abstract_session.dart:69:29)
> E/flutter (12889): #12     FFmpegSession.create
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_session.dart:40:43)
> E/flutter (12889): #13     FFmpegKit.executeWithArguments
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_kit.dart:44:29) E/flutter
> (12889): #14     FFmpegKit.execute
> (package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/ffmpeg_kit.dart:38:17) E/flutter
> (12889): #15     _shareMoments
> (package:carefour/presentation/maker/create_function.dart:217:19)
> E/flutter (12889): #16     compute.
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:19:20) E/flutter
> (12889): #17     _RemoteRunner._run (dart:isolate:1021:47) E/flutter
> (12889): #18     _RemoteRunner._remoteExecute (dart:isolate:1015:12)
> E/flutter (12889): #19     _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:17) E/flutter
> (12889): #20     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage
> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)

This is the code:

```
Future<bool> shareMoments(ComputeMomentModel data) async {
  File? imgFile;
  File? paletteFile;
  var uuid = const Uuid();
  String newUuid = uuid.v4();
  String finalImagePath = "momentGif-$newUuid.gif";
  String paletteFileName= "momentPalette-$newUuid.png";
  File? finalImage;
  finalImage = null;

  await FFmpegKit.execute('-i ${data.directoryPath}/image%d.png -vf palettegen ${data.directoryPath}/$paletteFileName').then((session) async {
    final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

    if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
      paletteFile = File("${data.directoryPath}/$paletteFileName");

      await FFmpegKit.execute('-f image2 -y -r 8 -i ${data.directoryPath}/image%d.png -i ${paletteFile?.path} -filter_complex fps=8,scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=max_colors=32[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=dither=bayer ${data.directoryPath}/$finalImagePath').then((session) async {
        final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
          finalImage = File("${data.directoryPath}/$finalImagePath");
        }
      });

    } else {
      debugPrint("Failed");
    }
  });

  // Below block to clear the cache - else ffmpeg keeps on creating the first one
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i<24; i++) {
    imgFile = File('${data.directoryPath}/image$i.png');
    imgFile.delete(recursive: true);
  }

  // —> Calling Backend API

  return true;

}
```

compute function

```
Future<bool> computeShareMoments({required String directoryPath}) async {
  ComputeCreateMomentModel data = ComputeMomentModel(null, directoryPath);
  return await compute(shareMoments, data);

}
```

Can anyone help with a solution? I am stuck for a while now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your error, i think you need to use [ensureInitialized](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html) to ensure that `BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.instance` is initialized in the compute function.

Comment: I have called ` WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in the main function.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this problem?, I'm facing the same

Comment: Was not able to run ffmpeg inside the compute function, but i was able to run ffmpeg in the background with the normal async function, and show a push notification based on the result.